# ImageMagick V7 and Cropping Tool

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, imagemagick

I'm trying to crop an image using ImageMagick V7 on Linux CentOS 7 via the following command-line:

```
$convert -crop 256x256+224+384 test2.png Cropped.png
```

My input image is test2.png, my output image is Cropped.png. The input image is 480x640, and I want to crop it to 256x256. 
The general form of the command-line is given by:

```
$convert -crop x_sizexy_size+x_offset+y_offset inputfile outputfile
```

ImageMagick cropping diagram:

[image: ImageMagick Cropping Diagram]

My original image looks like this:

[image: Original Image]

My cropped image looks like this:

[image: Cropped Image]

You can see there's whitespace in my original image, what I want is to remove that.

Comment: Could you please consider accepting @Bonzo 's answer rather than mine as he was first.

Comment: Alright added. Thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works OK for me but your dimensions are a bit off - for the result I think you wanted.

Note V7 uses magick and not convert; convert uses a V6 legacy version.

You should read the input image ( in most cases ) before any operation. In V7 if you use the commands in the wrong order it can fail.

I used:

```
$magick test2.png -crop 256x256+224+384 Cropped.png
```

In this case if you only wanted to remove the white area you could use -trim:

```
$magick test2.png -trim Cropped.png
```

Comment: Add +repage after the crop or trim to avoid keeping the virtual canvas for PNG output, which may mess up further processing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you suggested `-trim` when I answered - I thought you were just correcting the `-crop` syntax. I should have read more carefully - I am deleting my answer.

Comment: Ugh! I can't. If won't let me delete the accepted answer. I'll ask OP to accept your answer as it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are trying to trim whitespace, in which case you'd be better using `-trim` as it will trim correctly regardless of colour (provided it is solid) and regardless of the amount of trimming required:

```
magick input.png -trim +repage result.png
```

[image]

I have added a red border purely for display purposes so you can see the extent of the cropped image even on Stack Overflow's white background.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how long I've spent trying to resolve this.